# Propagate the password change among all the devices

Tags: lumia, outlook, windows-live, nokia-lumia-1020

I recently changed my password of my Windows Live account (handling my outlook, OneDrive).

My Lumia 1020 is also connected to this account. I noticed though that I can still view my emails on the phone.

Is there a way to force (from the web) anything connected to this account to either sign in or provide the new password when trying to access e-mails ?

Comment: I've tried to simulate what you wanted. In my case I needed to change the password on the phone to get it sync again. My account was almost lock because the phone tried the (now) wrong password many times.

Comment: That's what happened when trying to access SkyDrive. The problem was with the mail, I was easily able to access e-mails after changing the password. That's a bit strange.

Comment: You sure you don't use app passwords? Don't know if when you change password the app passwords are cleared too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Basically, when I bought the phone I entered my Windows Live account, and it automatically synced with Outlook and SkyDrive. That's all.

Comment: I mean in your Microsoft Account you can specify a highter level of security by using two factor authentication. In this case apps (or WIndows Phone) will log accept you main password. Intead of this you must genereate an app password specific to the phone.

Comment: What device did you change the password from?